# Javascript switch case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have following code:

```
function SetStartDateIfNull(date, range_id) {
if (date || isEmpty(date)) {
    switch (range_id) {
        case 0:
            date = date.getDate() - 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            date = date.getDate() - 30;
            break;
        case 2:
            date = date.getMonth() - 6;
            break;
        case 3:
            date = date.getYear() - 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            date = date.getYear() - 15;
            break;
    } //end switch
} //end if
return date;
} //end SetStartDateIfNull
```

my intention if date is null, I set date. I debugged the code. "if" statement is working. If date is null it entire the if block. But it skips the switch block. In debugging, `range_id = 0;` and `date = "";` Why it skips the all switch block?

UPDATE

this code is working.

```
function SetEndDateIfNull(date) {
    if (date || isEmpty(date)) {
        date = new Date();
    }
    return date;
} //end SetDateIfNull
```

Thanks.

Comment: What value of `date` do you pass to the function?

Comment: `SetStartDateIfNull(new Date(), 0)` yields `14` when I try it.

Comment: `date = "";` and `range_id = 0;`. I wrote this in my question.

Comment: what *type* is `range_id`? The cases test for `Numeric`, so it would fail if it is a string (e.g. `'0'`) as switch uses `===` for comparison.

Comment: range id is a form element id. (anchor id)

Comment: then it's propably a string. use `parseInt(range_id, 10)` somewhere before you pass it to the switch. Or `switch (parseInt(range_id, 10)) {` or use strings for the cases. e.g. `case "1":`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function, you are checking if the date is null, but in your cases you are trying to get date from undefined variable.

```
function SetStartDateIfNull(date, range_id) {
    if (!date || isEmpty(date)) {
        var date = new Date();//date is undefined
        switch (range_id) {
            case 0:
                date = date.getDate() - 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                date = date.getDate() - 30;
                break;
            case 2:
                date = date.getMonth() - 6;
                break;
            case 3:
                date = date.getYear() - 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                date = date.getYear() - 15;
                break;
        } //end switch 
      } //end if
    return date;
    } //end SetStartDateIfNull
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q42mp/)

Comment: Now, Is not working with IE.(It works with Chrome and FireFox)

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi which version are you using, my fiddle is working on IE

Comment: It works. I think there is a cache problem. Thanks a lot, again

Answer (score 3):

Very strange code.
Methods getDate, getMonth and getYear return integer value;
But for run with this method date must be object.
I think your code going into switch and then generate error or exception, because date is NULL and can't call any methods.

Comment: Yes. Im new javascript. I want to add days or months. But getDate is returns date number. I thought C# logic. But it is diffrent. I want to add dateInterval to allDateTime. (not only to days, times, etc.) For example, when I add -40 days it returns -x. But in c# it return date of 40 days ago.

Comment: Is there any tutorial about this.also, Thanks for attention.

Comment: You can read this, for example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 1):

Check out this line

```
if (!date || isEmpty(date))
```

Comment: yes this is right. I forgot to use "!". But this is not answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition will evaluate to false if date is null. `if (date)` returns `false` if date is null. Not sure what you're missing. You want to do:

```
if (!date || isEmpty(date)) {
```

Comment: It is entering the if block. There is no problem about "if".

Comment: Sorry but I'm have problems following your post. Can you fix this typo?

If date is null it entire the if block